If $f:\mathbb{R}\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f(x,0)=f(x,1)$
I've been struggling on one small part of a question for while, and I think I am just missing something that should be quite obvious.
The question:
Suppose $Y=\left \{0,1\right \}$ is equipped with the indiscrete topology.
Show that if $f:\mathbb{R}\times Y\to\mathbb{R} $ is continuous then $f(x,0)=f(x,1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
This is my thinking:
Let $a=f(x,0),b=f(x,1)$. Suppose $a\neq b$.
Let $U=f^{-1}((a-\frac{a+b}{2},a+\frac{a+b}{2}))$. Then $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times Y$.
Open sets in this topology have to be a union of sets of the form $A\times B$, where A is open in $\mathbb{R}$, and B is open in Y. You know that $(x,0)\in U$ so there must be some open $A_x\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,0)\in A_x\times B_x$.
$B_x$ has to be open in $Y$ but it is not the empty set so $B_x=Y$. Then $(x,1)\in A_x\times B_x$. This contradicts our assumption.
Can someone check whether this proof is correct, or give me a hint if there is a better way to approach this question.

Also, that you can just fix $x$ and show the composite $Y \to Y \times \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ is constant. But this is clear as the preimage of any point is closed and hence either empty or $Y$

Your idea is good, but your proof is not correct.
Letting $a = f (x \times 0)$ and $b = f (x \times 1)$, you assume that $a \ne b$ and want to derive a contradiction. You then chose a neighborhood of $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $U = f^{-1} \left( \left( a - \frac{a + b}{2}, a + \frac{a + b}{2} \right) \right)$. I suppose your idea was to exclude $b$, but this choice doesn't necessarily do that: for example, if $a = 1$ and $b = 2$, then the interval is $\left( -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2} \right)$, of which $2$ is a member (and you would have no contradiction).
Instead, I would choose $V = f^{-1} \left( \left( a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon \right) \right)$, where $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} |b - a|$. Here, we clearly have that $x \times 1 \notin V$ (in fact, this would even be the case if you let $\varepsilon = |b - a|$). Then, proceeding as you have done, we have that $x \times 0 \in V$, and since $V$ is open by continuity of $f$, then there must be some basis element $V_0 \times Y$ of the product topology on $\mathbb{R} \times Y$ that contains $x \times 0$ and is contained in $V$ (the second factor must be $Y$ because it cannot be empty). Then, since $x \in V_0$ and $1 \in Y$, then $x \times 1 \in V_0 \times Y$, which shows that $x \times 1 \in V$. Here, we do arrive at a contradiction, and the statement is proved.
